# How this command "preprocessing.scale" do in term of math?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have read the manual in scikit learn website and i still don't know what is the mathematical formula behind this command.

```
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
...               [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
...               [ 0.,  1., -1.]])
>>> X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X)

>>> X_scaled                                          
array([[ 0.  ..., -1.22...,  1.33...],
       [ 1.22...,  0.  ..., -0.26...],
       [-1.22...,  1.22..., -1.06...]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center to the mean and component wise scale to unit variance.

This means that mean value along the axis is subtracted from X and the resulting value is divided by std along the axis.

Comment: Thank you Andrey. But I still dont understand it might because of my english skill. Could you explain more clearly by showing the equation of this example above?

Comment: Sure. In this case the calculation is the following: (X - np.mean(X, axis=0)) / (np.std(X, axis=0))

Answer (score 0):

Andrey's formula in the comments is correct - I'd just add that numpy and scikit-learn use the population formula for calculating the standard deviation, not the sample standard deviation, which is the default in other languages like R. So numpy and scikit-learn divide the sum of squares by `n`, instead of `n-1`.